# header files for image denoising in opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv, header

I have seen the function fastNlMeansDenoising,denoise_TVL1,fastNlMeansDenoisingColored in opencv documentation. My question is what is the header file to include in my code so that I can use those functions. I am using VS as IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> photo.hpp

is the header that you are looking for.